# How to prove a = b → a + 1 = b + 1 in lean?

Tags: dependent-type, formal-verification, lean

I'm working my way through the chapter 4 of the [lean tutorial](https://leanprover.github.io/tutorial/).

I'd like to be able to prove simple equalities, such as `a = b → a + 1 = b + 1` **without** having to use the calc environment. In other words I'd like to explicitly construct the proof term of:

`example (a b : nat) (H1 : a = b) : a + 1 = b + 1 := sorry`

My best guess is that I need to use `eq.subst` and some relevant lemma about equality on natural numbers from the standard library, but I'm at loss. The closest lean example I can find is this:

`example (A : Type) (a b : A) (P : A → Prop) (H1 : a = b) (H2 : P a) : P b :=
eq.subst H1 H2`

Comment: Please note that the linked tutorial is for *Lean 2*. You can find documentation for the current version of Lean at http://leanprover.github.io/documentation/.

Comment: Thanks @Kha, I can see that lean 3 includes a newer, improved version of the tutorial:
https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/
 (at least without unimplemented TODOs), I'll switch and use it accordingly.

Comment: BTW, this new version of the tutorial is super-cool, it shows the types of terms on mouse-hover!

Comment: Unfortunately, the [feature appears to have a bug](https://github.com/leanprover/leanprover.github.io/issues/61)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `congr_arg` is a good solution in general, this specific example can indeed be solved with `eq.subst` + higher-order unification (which `congr_arg` uses internally).

```
example (a b : nat) (H1 : a = b) : a + 1 = b + 1 :=
eq.subst H1 rfl
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`congrArg`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#congrArg) lemma

```
lemma congrArg {α : Sort u} {β : Sort v} {a₁ a₂ : α} (f : α → β) :
  a₁ = a₂ → f a₁ = f a₂
```

which means if you supply equal inputs to a function, the output values will be equal too.

The proof goes like this:

```
example (a b : Nat) (h : a = b) : a + 1 = b + 1 :=
  congrArg (fun n => n + 1) h
```

Note, that Lean is able to infer that our function is `fun n => n + 1`, so the proof can be simplified into `congrArg _ h`.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works, and from now on I will know how to use `congr_arg`. However, I don't understand the type declaration of `congr_arg`. The unknowns are:

1. Universe variables `u v`. Are they covered further in lean tutorial?
2. `Sort` keyword.

Is there any place I could get a quick understanding of these, or should I just patiently carry on with the tutorial?

Comment: Universe variables are covered in sect. 2.2 of [Theorem Proving in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/). [issue #1341](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/issues/1341) explains the `Sort` keyword. *For now* you can just ignore these subtleties and think of the `congr_arg` lemma as a function that produces a proof of `f a₁ = f a₂` from a proof of `a₁ = a₂`, for any function `f : α → β`, where `Sort` just tells you that `α` and `β` are some types. HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have an equality (`a = b`), you can also rewrite the goal using tactic mode:

```
example (a b : nat) (H1 : a = b) : a + 1 = b + 1 :=
by rw H1
```

See [Chapter 5 of *Theorem Proving in Lean*](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/tactics.html) for an introduction to tactics.

Answer (score 1):

More general :  a = b -> a + c = b + c  in a Ring

```
import algebra.ring
open algebra

variable {A : Type}

variables [s : ring A] (a b c : A)
include s

example (a b c : A) (H1 : a = b) : a + c = b + c :=
eq.subst H1 rfl
```